# kernel error: Nouveau problem with Xorg: nv50cal_space: -16

Tags: kernel, xorg, nouveau

Running KDE Neon 16.04 LTS x86_64. After some time working, display starts behaving buggy and laggy, sound stops, and when I try to Alt+F1 there are constantly output of nouveau logs.

I grep this from the kern.log, as is the same output I got almost every time:

```
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11604.483927] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11604.483933] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11604.483968] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11607.093232] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11607.093254] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11607.094997] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11614.658725] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11614.742241] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 614900 00800000 (1d408200)
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11614.903598] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11614.903745] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jun 10 18:00:56 davdriver-desktop kernel: [11614.989329] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.825964] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.826118] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GM107 (117010a2)
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.942422] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 82.07.32.40.24
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.943674] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB GDDR5
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241585] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 2048 MiB
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241587] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241590] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241592] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241594] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 01000f02 00020030
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241597] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02000f00 00000000
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241598] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 08011f82 00020030
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241600] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 02022f62 00020010
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241602] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 04033f72 00020010
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241604] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00001030
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241605] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00010131
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241606] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00002261
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.241608] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00020361
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.294181] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.395406] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff88032a597000
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.395519] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.395623] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
Jun 11 14:54:45 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.405351] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4032.524481] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4032.524486] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4032.524533] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4033.379035] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4033.379061] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4033.380707] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4039.009135] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4039.112518] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 614900 00800000 (19408200)
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4039.238192] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4039.238299] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jun 11 15:45:06 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4039.323760] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.319493] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.319498] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.319524] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.379205] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.379225] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4066.380649] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4070.979418] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4071.082739] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 614900 00800000 (1e408200)
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4071.210003] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4071.210110] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jun 11 18:17:39 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 4071.295628] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.839709] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.839847] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GM107 (117010a2)
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.954396] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 82.07.32.40.24
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.955577] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB GDDR5
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254267] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 2048 MiB
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254269] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254273] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254275] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254277] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 01000f02 00020030
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254279] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02000f00 00000000
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254281] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 08011f82 00020030
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254283] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 02022f62 00020010
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254284] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 04033f72 00020010
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254286] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00001030
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254287] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00010131
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254289] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00002261
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.254290] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00020361
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.306804] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.396410] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff88032a594400
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.396479] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.396585] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
Jun 12 14:06:52 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.410126] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14742.213110] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14742.213117] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14742.213179] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14744.330819] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14744.330841] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14744.332599] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14751.357855] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14751.461208] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 614900 00800000 (19408200)
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14751.611855] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14751.611994] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jun 12 18:51:46 davdriver-desktop kernel: [14751.697508] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.830447] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.830605] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GM107 (117010a2)
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.945166] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 82.07.32.40.24
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.946564] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB GDDR5
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246017] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 2048 MiB
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246018] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246022] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246024] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246026] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 01000f02 00020030
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246029] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02000f00 00000000
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246031] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 08011f82 00020030
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246032] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 02022f62 00020010
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246034] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 04033f72 00020010
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246036] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00001030
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246038] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00010131
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246039] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00002261
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.246041] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00020361
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.298668] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.400502] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff8800ba2da800
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.400640] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.400743] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
Jun 13 15:00:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.409869] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6848.652507] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6848.652513] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6848.652542] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6850.214275] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6850.214298] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6850.216025] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6857.240530] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6857.343838] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 614900 00800000 (1a408200)
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6857.494376] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6857.494507] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
Jun 13 18:20:58 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 6857.579960] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.834751] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.834887] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GM107 (117010a2)
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.949525] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 82.07.32.40.24
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    1.950741] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 2048 MiB GDDR5
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249727] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 2048 MiB
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249729] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249732] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249734] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249736] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 01000f02 00020030
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249738] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 02000f00 00000000
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249740] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 08011f82 00020030
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249742] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 03: 02022f62 00020010
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249743] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 04: 04033f72 00020010
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249745] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00001030
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249746] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 00010131
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249748] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 02: 00002261
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.249749] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 03: 00020361
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.302252] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.404306] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x60000, bo ffff880329db4c00
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.404420] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.404523] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
Jun 14 14:30:29 davdriver-desktop kernel: [    3.413544] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.277756] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.277771] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000000 [] warp 3f0009 [ILLEGAL_INSTR_ENCODING]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.281793] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.281807] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 6000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.281816] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3c0001 [STACK_ERROR]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.293410] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.293428] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 60009 [ILLEGAL_INSTR_ENCODING]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.293438] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 40009 [ILLEGAL_INSTR_ENCODING]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.293456] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.293469] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004
...
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310623] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 2d000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310636] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310645] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 22000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310653] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 1000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310665] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310674] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310680] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 1000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310692] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 2 [007fa09000 Xorg[1527]]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310705] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3f000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:51 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2922.310714] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC1/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 23000d [OOR_REG]
Jun 14 13:18:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2926.632055] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Jun 14 13:18:55 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2926.632062] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: sw engine fault on channel 10, recovering...
...
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.311091] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.432219] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.551145] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.666605] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.780072] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.893727] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2930.927513] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2931.009838] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:18:59 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2931.124628] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
Jun 14 13:19:00 davdriver-desktop kernel: [ 2931.243627] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1527]: nv50cal_space: -16
...
```

*`davdriver-desktop` is the system name.*

I am sorry for not giving more information or how to search for any kind of solution since I have no idea what could be the problem. I can work for hours without any problem, and these things occur sometimes, some days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, seeing this on Fedora 29, with an `NVIDIA Corporation G94GL [Quadro FX 1800] (rev a1)`  and `xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.15-6.fc29.x86_64`. The whole console, keyboard, mouse, video, audio froze. I could still log in from another machine, which helped in rebooting, but I actually had to powercycle for the graphics to start working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v50cal_space` errors basically mean that the GPU has hung and it happens when we're out of IB space for `pushbuf` submission. Source: [Ilia's comment](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92833#c1).

There are few bugs related to `nv50cal_space` which can be found at [bugs.freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=nv50cal_space&list_id=663471&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&query_format=specific), especially: [#93629](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93629), [#99900](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99900) and [#100567](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100567) (which are related to `CTXSW_TIMEOUT`).

Related posts:

- [Ubuntu 16.04 desktop hangs occasionally during regular use](https://askubuntu.com/q/874307/78223)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 desktop hangs approximately 1x per day](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036581/78223)
- [Ubuntu showing sched_error 20[ ] on boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/897627/78223)

The workaround is to install [NVIDIA drivers](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/78223), which replaces nouveau kernel extension.

Comment: Glad to know it is a known bug, do you know if this also happen with ATI/AMD GPUs?

Comment: no it doesn't, noveau is for Nvidia GPU's afaik.   AMD != NVIDIA

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the kernel option `nomodeset` to the booting options.
It will at least make the system usable.

I have the same problem and this is the only thing that helped at all.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was almost 6 years ago and things may have changed a lot (I have no idea right now, as I do not have that computer anymore), but thanks for answering anyway!